# leaflet snap polyline to rout

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I'm try to convert polyline to  rout but I have a problem
You see in the picture below that the road is different from the polyline:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([32.661343, 51.680374], 6);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mymap);
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
var markerList = [];
var a = [];
var myTrip = [];
var myTrip2 = [];
for (var i = 1; i < locations.length ; i++) {
    myTrip.push(new L.LatLng(parseFloat(locations[i]['Received']['lat']),parseFloat(locations[i]['Received']['lng'])));
    a[0] =  parseFloat(locations[i]['Received']['lat']);
    a[1] = parseFloat(locations[i]['Received']['lng']);
  var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]));
    marker.bindPopup((locations[i]['Received']['id']).toString());
    markerList.push(marker);

    var polyline =L.polyline(myTrip, {color: 'blue'}).addTo(mymap);

}
var markerPatterns = L.polylineDecorator(myTrip, {
    patterns: [
        {offset: 25, repeat: 50, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 15, pathOptions: {fillOpacity: 1, weight: 0}})}
    ]
}).addTo(mymap);
var control = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: myTrip,
    show: false,
    waypointMode: 'snap',
    showAlternatives: true,
    useZoomParameter: true,
    createMarker: function() {}
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What are the data sources you are using?

Comment: My problem is creating the wrong path, the paths outlined in the image are extra and wrong. I read the LAT and LNG from the database.

Comment: Where does your basemap come from? Where do the routes come from? Where do the marker's lat-lngs come from? These are different questions.

Comment: @IvanSanchez The base map is OSRM demo. The lat and lng come from the GPS sensor then are stored in the database and the rout and marker are created based on them.

Comment: As you can see in the picture, the blue line is the correct path that is plotted with the polyline, and the red lines are created using the rout machine, which includes the wrong and additional high and low streets.

Answer (score 1):

1) So are the lines drawn using the raw coordinates? In other words, are the lines drawn like you do not use a routing service?

2) Leaflet Routing Machine is a plug-in that supports several routing engines, with OSRM as a default.

http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/

Have you tried inserting your DB coordinates to the OSRM-demo? Is it giving you the expected results?

http://map.project-osrm.org/

Comment: The code specifies that I will use this plugin but will not get the desired result

Comment: @MortezaFathi, oh, i am sorry.. I edited my post, trying to be helpful.

Comment: As you can see in the picture, the blue line is the correct path that is plotted with the polyline, and the red lines are created using the Routing machine, which includes the wrong and additional high and low streets.

Answer (score -1):

The high and low streets are routes because 1 of your waypoints are hitting that street and to get back on track again it have to turn around the block. It would have routed correcly if your waypoints where more accurate.